# Execution failed for task ':common:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating android studio to 4.2, I am facing the below error in my project.

```
    Execution failed for task ':common:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

My build.gradle file like

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had met this problem after upgrade to version 4.2.

I try to upgrade gradle version

project#gradle-wrapper.properties -> change distributionUrl like below

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

sync project.

Comment: I posted an issue, here is their answer. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187851912